# Android-How to compress existed video or audio files(.mp4,.mp3)?

Tags: android, compression, media

My Project is Based on **Android4.0(API 14)** and I need to select Video files or Audio files to upload to server.Since they can't be too large i have to compress them.

I can't use ffmpeg because it's too large for my project

MediaCode API seems needs 16 at minimum and before 18 very very hard to use and from 18 very hard to use

so where's the lightweight plan

Comment: .mp4s and mp3s are already compressed data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my question i mean change the byteRate and frameRate and so on.I use INDE Media Pack for Android4.3 and higher now.